# static_cast void* char* vs static_cast void** char**

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

If I do the following all is ok:

```
char* cp = "abc";
void* vp = NULL;
vp = static_cast<void*>(cp);//ok
cp = static_cast<char*>(vp);//ok
```

But the following is not:

```
char** cpp = &cp;
void** vpp = NULL;
vpp = static_cast<void**>(cpp);//error C2440: 'static_cast':
                               //cannot convert from 'char **' to 'void **'
cpp = static_cast<char**>(vpp);//error C2440: 'static_cast':
                               //cannot convert from 'void **' to 'char **'
```

Please can someone explain to me why the second examples are not allowed. Please don't quote the C++ standard as your whole answer, because I've already seen answers that quote it, and I don't understand what they meant. I want to understand **why** the second examples don't work (ie. if you could give an example where it would be dangerous that would be a great help). Because I don't get it. To me, both examples are casting pointers. Why does an additional level of indirection make any difference?

Comment: You can implicitly convert any pointer to a `void *`, and static-cast in the reverse direction. But this is not true for `T*` and `U*` in general, which are unrelated. (Now think `T = char*` and `U = void*`.)

Comment: You can cast a `char**` to a `void*` and vice-versa.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - Yes, but why is this not allowed? When would this be unsafe?

Answer (score 12):

A `void *` pointer can point at "anything", and it is valid to convert all pointers to a `void *`, and it is valid to convert all pointers from `void *` to some other type.

However, a `void **` is a pointer that points to a `void *` value. And a `char **` is a pointer that points to `char *` value. These types don't point to the types that are convertible from one another. You can, if you NEED to do this, use `void **vpp = reinterpret_cast<void **>(cpp);`, but it's "not safe" (you are basically telling the compiler "Look, I know what I'm doing here, so just do it", which may not do what you actually expected...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. If some string has the address 0x12345678, I can put that in my char* or my void*. If the address of my char* is 0x87654321, why can't I put that value (the address 0x87654321) in my void**? ie. why is it ok to static_cast 0x12345678 to a void*, but not ok to static_cast 0x87654321 to a void**? When/why would this ever be unsafe?

Comment: @e244: The issue is that you can easily (and without any explicit cast) subvert the type system if that conversion was allowed. I have provided a longer explanation as an answer, but the short description would be that the double pointer allows you to change data in unsafe ways.

Comment: Can `void*` point to a function (i.e is a function pointer convertible to `void*`)?

Comment: @rubenvb: Not guaranteed by the standard, the issue is that in some platforms the address space for code and data might be of different sizes

Answer (score 6):

The restriction is to avoid breaking the type system. The first conversion is fine:

```
type *p = ...;
void *vp = p;
```

While you are giving away the type, you cannot *inflict* too much damage to the original value without since there is little to be done with a `void` object and all changes to `vp` are local to the pointer and cannot affect `p`.

If the second case was allowed:

```
type **p = ...;
void **vp = p;
```

Then perfectly looking and correct code could break your application. For example:

```
int *parray[10];
int **p = parray;
void **vp = p;
*vp = new double();  // now parray[0] is a pointer to a double object, 
                     // not a pointer to an int!!!
```

The type system has been subverted.

That is, the problem is that in the second case there are operations that can be applied to the destination pointer that can modify the original object and cause bugs. Similar examples can be found with `const` other cases (you can convert `int*` to `const int*`, but you cannot convert `int**` to `const int**`...).