# reinterpret_cast of pointer-to-pointer - is it Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

We need to cast `int**` to `void**`, for which `reinterpret_cast` can be used. However, is it technically allowed by the C++ Standard, or are we in Undefined Behavior territory?

**Use case**

When using Nvidia libraries we need to use pointer-to-pointer:

```cpp
cudaMalloc(void** ptr, size_t size);
```

So a typical solution is:

```cpp
int* p;
cudaMalloc(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p), 123);
```

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#13 as long as alignment requirement is satisfied, casting is ok…

Comment: Related: [static_cast void* char* vs static_cast void** char**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16280814/11082165)

Comment: …but accessing through `*ptr` would be strict aliasing violation

Comment: Note that `void**` is not a `void*`.  The implications being that it's "okay" (with caveats and flashing red lights) to cast to/from a `void*`, but the same affordance is not transitive to `void**`.

Comment: A possibly better solution would be something like `void* p; cudaMalloc(&p, N * sizeof(int)); int* pi = static_cast<int*>(p);` A *real* solution would of course require error checking.

Comment: Pointer handled by ```cudaMalloc```, as far as I understand, have only meaning within ```cuda```: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145913/perform-arithmetic-on-a-pointer-returned-using-cudamalloc-in-host-code. Thus using it on host for anything else than passing it from and to ```cuda``` functions would be UB I think. Am I wrong? [cuda documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc63ffd93e344b939d6399199d8b12fef.html) is not very explicit on this subject.

Comment: COM also routinely requires this: `ISomeInterface* p; someObj->QueryInterface(IID_ISomeInterface, (void**)&p);` So practically speaking, compilers have to handle this reasonably, as this is a common pattern.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: COM code is definitely not intended to be portable, and it does make a whole lot of Windows-centric assumptions that are not valid on some embedded architectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast itself is permitted, but is not practically useful under the guarantees made by the standard, because any non-trivial use of the result will eventually cause undefined behavior.

Specifically, if `alignof(void**) > alignof(int**)`, then it is possible that the original pointer is not suitably aligned for `void**` and then the result of the cast would be unspecified and practically any use of the result would consequently cause undefined behavior. It is then impossible to cast back to the original value as well.

Otherwise, the cast, passing the pointer around and cast back to `int**` are all permitted. However accessing through the `void**` (e.g. to write a pointer value into the provided pointer-to-pointer) will be an aliasing violation, because `void*` can't alias `int*`. So if `cudaMalloc` accesses the pointer without first casting back to `int**`, then the behavior is undefined.

That's all the C++ standard has to say on this. Given that you seem to be asking about CUDA specifically, its specification can of course make additional guarantees. And that's probably going to be very significant in practice.

However, if you consider this as some generic `malloc`-like implementation, then it is impossible to write this function so that this usage pattern would have defined behavior, because the function wouldn't be able to know to which pointer type it must cast back to first. And that's not only a theoretical concern. Many compilers do make use of this type of UB from aliasing violations for optimization.

The correct pattern that can be implemented without aliasing violation and UB would instead be something like

```
void* p_temp;
cudaMalloc(&p_temp, 123);
auto p = static_cast<int*>(p_temp);
```

Comment: The Standard does not guarantee that `sizeof (int*) == sizeof (void*)`, let alone that they have the same representation.  So the first sentence is horribly wrong.  Your final code snippet is correct.

Comment: @BenVoigt Neither of those affect anything I said in my answer. I could have maybe added "Many compilers do make use of this type of UB from aliasing violations for optimization, _even if size and representation of the pointer types are the same_." for emphasis though. The first sentence is correct. You are allowed to cast any object pointer type to any other object pointer type with `reinterpret_cast`. This evaluation itself will never cause UB (except maybe for the implementation-defined behavior of invalid pointer values).

Comment: That's an interesting way to use "fine".

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you have a suggestion for a better choice of words?

Comment: Perhaps "The cast itself is permitted, but may not have useful or even predictable results".  The part about possibly invalid `int**` value is a red herring because `&p` is the address of a variable, and cannot possibly be invalid unless the world has already ended (stack overflow for example).

Comment: @BenVoigt True on the invalid pointer part when considering OP's example. I tried to incorporate your suggestions into an edit.

Comment: @BenVoigt Do you know of an implementation where `sizeof (int*) != sizeof (void*)`?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: See https://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html for at least four examples.

Comment: @BenVoigt Interesting source; although I'm tempted to say "I see only one ('Older, word-addressed Prime machines'), and it predates ANSI C". The other ones are different *representations*. I also note that the old HP 3000 machine had "address performance problems" (no kidding!).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: I suppose that's the difference between trashing the pointer (if wrong representation) vs trashing the pointer and also something next to it (if wrong size).  Either is generally fatal to the program, although the wrong-size variant might be considerably more confusing to debug.